# Prevent container from growing when legend text gets displayed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to stop the container of my image and subtext from growing when the text becomes displayed on hover. At the moment on hover you can see the *portfolio__item* element resize to fit the text in and it's background color appear at the bottom.

I've tried using a position: absolute on the text but it then makes positioning the text in the middle of the image almost impossible.

Here's a code pen i've made that's a replica of what i'm working on:
https://codepen.io/Olivier42M/pen/oNzwGEL

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div class="portfolio">
    <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
      <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
    </a>
     <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
      <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
    </a>
     <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
      <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
    </a>
     <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
      <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
    </a>
     <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
      <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
    </a>
   
 </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
  text-aligne: center;
}

.portfolio {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.portfolio__item {
    background-color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.portfolio__img {
    transition: 
        transform 750ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .5, 1),
        opacity 250ms linear;
}


.portfolio__item:focus {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio__img:hover,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: .75;
}

.portfolio__text{
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 3em;
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: 
        opacity 500ms linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__text{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the effect of enlarging the picture to work without increasing the borders, you need to set a fixed height for the parent container (`<a>` tag) of the `<img>` tag. I marked all edits in css.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    
    grid-gap: 10px; /*add this it*/
}

.portfolio__item {
    background-color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; /*add this it*/
    height: 400px; /*add this it*/
}

.portfolio__img {
    transition: 
        transform 750ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .5, 1),
        opacity 250ms linear;
}


.portfolio__item:focus {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio__img:hover,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: .75;
}

.portfolio__text{
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 3em;
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: 
        opacity 500ms linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__text{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="portfolio">
     <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
       <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
     </a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
       <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
     </a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
       <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
     </a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
       <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
     </a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKuGA17.jpeg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
       <div class="portfolio__text">Legend text</div>
     </a>
    
  </div>
</div>
```